# How does numerical order play with numerical randomisation?

Tags: probability, random-variables

A huge lorry carrying 6 million dice overturns, scattering its load across the highway. I would envisage that, if we counted all the 1’s showing, there would be, roughly, 1 million. There would also be 1 million 2’s, 1 million 3’s and so on, more or less.
If another dice-laden lorry crashed with the same outcome and we add the 1’s, the 2’s etc, to the original totals of the first lorry, I would envisage a more equal distribution of numbers becomes evident.
The more lorries crash, the more dice spill out and the more we add up the totals, the closer we get to a true 1:6 ratio for each number. Each lorry makes it more and more likely that a regular spread of numbers appears. Am I right in thinking this? If so, how does this scenario relate to the probability of some lorry at some point overturning and all 6 million dice show 6?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Sure, eventually you'll get $6$ million $6's$ but by that point you'll have seen so many values that this one outlier won't matter.  Or were you asking something else?

Comment: Monster math:  you expect it to take $6^{6000000}$ spills to get this one exotic outcome.  That's more than $3.15\times 10^{4668907}$.  Faced with that preposterously large number, your $6000000$ extra $6's$ won't even register.

Comment: @lulu: I wonder where you'd put all those dice (let alone the trucks)! If the volume of the observable universe is about $4\times 10^{86} {\rm  cm}^3$, and a small die is about $1 {\rm cm}^3$, you would quickly run out of space to put them. Plus who would have time to check all the individual die rolls?

Comment: @paw88789  Seriously.  Even if each die is the size of a proton, I think you run into problems.  The Eddington number, number of protons in the observable universe,  is like $10^{80}$ which is laughably low given the situation.